# Deep copy of array causes range error: maximum call stack size exceeded javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a deep copy of my array, which contains objects, with a code i found from stackoverflow in a thread which showed how to create a deep copy of an array.

```
alert("here"); //this is shown
var newArr = jQuery.extend(true,[],playerLst);
alert("here2") //this is not shown
var returnArr = [];
```

Error in console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Deepcopy of my objects is vital part of my project and would really need some help here.

Edit:

This is how my objects are valued, sorry for Estonian variables, i use them to make the code more clearer.

```
for(var i = 0; i<myValues.length;i++){
       var Player = new Object();
       var name = myValues[i];
       Player["name"] = name;
       Player["voor_1"] = 0;
       Player["voor_2"] = 0;
       Player["voor_3"] = 0;
       Player["voor_4"] = 0;
       Player["voor_5"] = 0;
       Player["voor_6"] = 0;
       Player["voor_7"] = 0;
       Player["punkte"] = 0;
       Player["koef"] = 0;
       Player["suhe"] = "0:0";
       Player["koht"] = i+1;
       Player["playedNames"] = [];
       playerLst.push(Player);
   }
```

E3:

[image: Picture of console]

Comment: It probably means that your source object has reference cycles. Without seeing your source data structure, it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: Could you please be more specific at what could i provide for more? Objects properties which are located inside playerLst? English is not my mother tongue and i have some trouble understanding, i'm sorry :)

Comment: If your object has a **reference cycle** , it means that one part of the object references another part. As the deep-copy code "explores" the object, it will encounter the cycle and get stuck there, copying and re-copying parts of the object over and over again. You did not post the structure of "playersLst" so I don't know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Well that structure shouldn't cause a problem, unless the "myValues" array involves objects with cyclic references. If you add `console.dir(playerLst);` before the `jQuery.extend()` call, you might be able to see what's wrong via the browser developer console. The console should get just as confused as jQuery if there are cycles.

Comment: Added picture of console log, it isn't perfect but should be able to understand what's going on? Any ideas?

Comment: Does one Object point to another object in the same array?

Comment: Yes, it has an array of hasPlayed which is full of other same named objects, is it an issue?

Comment: What means "is full of other same named objects"?

Comment: Well, the so called objects in there are "Players" and they're meant for tournament table called Swiss System. In this particular system it is important that none of the players play twice with the same opponent so i keep the names of players (actually not just names, the whole player objects) in the certain Player property hasPlayed which is an array. Might this cause the problem and should i add only names of the Players in hasPlayed not the whole objects (seems really stupid tbh).

Comment: Given a bigger thought on it, that's exactly what causes it - there are players inside the player. If the object player is copied it deepcopies also the player with all the elements in hasplayed which are also players and also have list called hasplayed. This is indeed a recursive loop which will never end. @Joriktos if you could write this as an answer, to change the hasPlayed into .name, then i could give you an accepted answer and my kudos. Pointed me probably in a right direction, can't currently recode but will do tomorrow and logically this must be the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing an object to another object in the same tree, so you're ending up in a cycle.

```
Players: {
    name1: {
        hasPlayedWith: name2 // *
    },
    name2: {
        hasPlayedWith: name1 // *
    }
}

/* deep copy now copies name2/name1,
which references back to name1/name2.
You're now ending up in a never ending loop,
named circular reference
(or reference cycle, circular structure, ...) */
```

To avoid this, you can save the name of the player as string and then call it with Players['name']

```
Players: {
    name1: {
        hasPlayedWith: 'name2'
    },
    name2: {
        hasPlayedWith: 'name1'
    }
}
```